# Regex are "(" and ")" necessary?

Tags: java, regex

Do I only have to use `(`and `)` if the pattern consists of multiple groups?

So if the pattern is `true|false` it doesn't matter if I add parenthesis or not, right? 
Then again, if the pattern is `POINT_PATTERN("\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)")` it does make a difference because I want to get two different values from it.

Can I write my current patterns, which are:

```
NUMBER_PATTERN("(?!(0[0-9]))[0-9]+"),
BOOLEAN_PATTERN("(true|false)"),
STRING_PATTERN("(\\w+)"),
INTEGER_PATTERN("/^([+-]?[1-9]\\d*|0)$/"),
```

as

```
NUMBER_PATTERN("(?!0[0-9])[0-9]+"),
BOOLEAN_PATTERN("true|false"),
STRING_PATTERN("\\w+"),
INTEGER_PATTERN("^[+-]?[1-9]\\d*|0$");
```

without any loss?

I am particularly unsure about `NUMER_PATTERN` and `INTEGER_PATTERN`. Is there any other reason why I shouldn't do this (bad coding style, ...)?

Comment: Parentheses are for capturing, do you want to capture: then you need them, if you don't, then you don't need them.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not necessarily, parentheses are generally also used for grouping things together. However, if you don't want to capture then you'd use `(?:pattern)` instead.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes True, I considered adding that to my comment, but in the examples shown, that wasn't relevant. Although, it could be relevant in the last one.

Comment: `final static PATTERN = Pattern.compile(String.format("test command (?<number>%s))"), InOutputStrings.NUMBER_PATTERN));   Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(argument); number = matcher.group("number");` - Why do Patterns work without parentheses here?

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake Because you don't call `matcher.group(1)`, so the capture group defined by the `(...)` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a sequence of characters or character classes is the default, and it is of higher precedence than the OR operator `|`. So if you don't have anything in front or behind your sequence (clearly displayed in your cases of `true|false`) then you don't need them.

However, if you want to use e.g. `this is true|false` for `"this is true"` or `"this is false"` then the precedence will fail for `"this is false"` and you need to group the `true|false`, for instance using a **non-capturing** group, e.g. `this is (?:true|false)`.

I don't see any problems with your expressions where you removed some of the parentheses. However, if you want to check them, then simply put them into an (online) checker that shows the precedence (e.g. [this one](https://regex101.com/)) and check if the resulting "explanation" changes. The various IDE plugings for regexp testing will hopefully also provide a similar *tree view* for you.

Beware that you are sometimes using boundary matchers (`^` and `$`) and sometimes you are not. I'd expect those to be either used or not used.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me!

Comment: *"I don't see any problems with your expressions"* The `INTEGER_PATTERN` is a problem without a group. Pattern `"^[+-]?[1-9]\\d*|0$"` would be a problem if using the `find()` method, because of the `|` OR operator. Since question doesn't specify whether `find()` or `matches()` is used, then it should be considered a problem.

Comment: Why would you use `find` with `^` and `$`?